# DateTime in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, datetime-format

I was importing internationalization for my app but I have a problem where I parse my `String` but it only returns the date and not the time. When I change the phone language, my format for the `Date` changes but my `Time` isn't showing.

This is when it is `EN_US` [image]

This is when it is `EU(German)`  [image]

That works well but my time format is missing...

This is the default String from the API: [image]

Here is the code:

```
/// I set a variable that calls the locale of the phone language and changes according to the phone preference
final f = DateFormat.yMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode);

/// where I dispay time and date but only date is shown in the pictures above
Text('Time and date: ${f.format(DateTime.parse(apicall.dateCreated))}');
```

My **questions** are: How do I show the time and how can I swap between showing the `Time` first then the `Date`, and opposite, if I want to show the `Date` first then the `Time`? (example `18-May-21 11:10h` and if I want to do this `11:10h 18-May-21`)
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should use `DateFormat.jm().add_yMd()`: this will show time first and then date. To swap it just use `DateFormat.yMd().add_jm()`
[More info here](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: This works but when I get a different type of data it says: `Invalid date format
2018 - 04 - 18T21:51:00`